# How did the variance and double summation of the covariance come to the L2 minimization equation?

Tags: machine-learning, papers, objective-functions, math

I am trying to understand the last two lines of this math notation (from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.04189.pdf)).

[image]

How did the Var and double summation of the Cov come to the equation?

The first two lines I understood something like $(a-b)^2 = a^2 -2ab +b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As in the second line, the first two terms are $\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}$, it means the variable of the expectation is $\hat{y}_i$ and you can take out $y_i$s from $\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}$s. Now we can use $\mathbb{E}\{\hat{y}_i\} = y_i$ and rewrite the terms of the second line likes the following:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i y_i)^2 = (\sum_i y_i)^2 \\
\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}\left[(\sum_i y_i)(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)\right] = (\sum_i y_i) \mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i \hat{y}_i) = (\sum_i y_i)^2
$$

The second line is written based on linearity of the expectation and $\mathbb{E}\{\hat{y}_i\} = y_i$. Hence, we can rewrite the second line like the following as $\sum_i y_i = \mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)$:

$$
\frac{1}{N^2}\left[\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)^2 - \left(\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)\right)^2\right]
$$

And the final step is using this formula $Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$  and take $X = \sum_i \hat{y}_i$:

$$
\frac{1}{N^2}\left[\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)^2 - \left(\mathbb{E}_{\hat{y}}(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)\right)^2\right] = \frac{1}{N^2} Var(\sum_i \hat{y}_i)
$$

From variance to covariance, you can use [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance): $$Var(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n cov(X_i, X_j)$$